# Add JavaScript Through Acumatica Customization

Tags: acumatica

I'm wondering if it's possible to add JavaScript code to an Acumatica web page through a customization.

Thanks for your help!

Fran Parker

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to create customization for existing page.
In Layout Editor select "Actions->Edit Aspx", 
add the following code

```
<px:PXLiteral runat="server" ID="s">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</px:PXLiteral>
```

and click "Generate customization script"

Comment: This is more recommended practice to add code to aspx other than creating a new aspx, as when you upgrade your version of ERP, this helps to inject the code to the new(if available) aspx page.

Comment: Hi! I tried this code but when I tried to generate it destroys the PXLiteral tag.

Comment: The latest version of Acumatica has build in ability to add Javascript to customization.

Comment: With PXLiteral control, you should add <px:PXLiteral runat="server" ID="s" /> tag first, then insert script through customization property editor. Content of PXLiteral control should encode html tags with &lt; &gt;

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. After I click on "Generate Customization Script" with the code in aspx, it rolls back to the original html script in aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You can add js code to your aspx page, and then add this page to your customization package. [Here](http://blog.zaletskyy.com/yuriy-zaletskyy-s-blog/how-to-disable-callback-from-checkboxes-in-acumatica) you can see example of adding js code.

Comment: Excuse me, could u tell me how to add JavaScript source into acumatica customization?